# Chainlink Large Responses not working with latest docs

Tags: solidity, chainlink

So, I was trying to follow the ChainLink's official docs for getting a large response as shown on [their website](https://docs.chain.link/docs/large-responses/) however I deployed, funded with link, called the requestBytes() function , waited some minutes and the data field is still empty. There have been a lot of people complaining about the same issue but the [answer for them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70716044/chainlink-any-api-large-response-example-doesnt-fulfill) was simply to follow the latest docs. Which I am. Is there still some step that I am missing ?

This is the contract code:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/blob/develop/contracts/src/v0.8/ChainlinkClient.sol";
// import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/ChainlinkClient.sol";


contract GenericLargeResponse is ChainlinkClient {
  using Chainlink for Chainlink.Request;

  bytes public data;
  string public image_url;

  constructor() {
    setChainlinkToken(0xa36085F69e2889c224210F603D836748e7dC0088);
    setChainlinkOracle(0x25C7ac1900de67605c0A1812109E960068B1C3d6);
  }

  function requestBytes() public
  {
    bytes32 specId = "b3b68ecd35464833a16613742640ae89";
    uint256 payment = 100000000000000000;
    Chainlink.Request memory req = buildChainlinkRequest(specId, address(this), this.fulfillBytes.selector);
    req.add("get","https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmZgsvrA1o1C8BGCrx6mHTqR1Ui1XqbCrtbMVrRLHtuPVD?filename=big-api-response.json");
    req.add("path", "image");
    sendOperatorRequest(req, payment);
  }

  event RequestFulfilled(
    bytes32 indexed requestId,
    bytes indexed data
  );

  function fulfillBytes(
    bytes32 requestId,
    bytes memory bytesData
  )
    public
    recordChainlinkFulfillment(requestId)
  {
    emit RequestFulfilled(requestId, bytesData);
    data = bytesData;
    image_url = string(data);
  }
}
```

Deployed on Kovan:https://kovan.etherscan.io/address/0x3B5fFfD84a0A36d3a66bCcF6de98B5dbaD102888.

The JSON file seems to be OK as well: https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmZgsvrA1o1C8BGCrx6mHTqR1Ui1XqbCrtbMVrRLHtuPVD?filename=big-api-response.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue with the large response job on the Kovan hosted node. Please try again with the following values:

```
  setChainlinkOracle(0x74EcC8Bdeb76F2C6760eD2dc8A46ca5e581fA656);

  bytes32 specId = "7da2702f37fd48e5b1b9a5715e3509b6";
```

Comment: it does work now indeed. Chainlink's docs are pretty confusing ngl. Is there maybe any other better guide available on the web to start using oracles ? Pls let me know if you have heard of any. Other than Chainlink works too.